A family of analytic functions F which is uniformly bounded on a domain D is equicontinuous on each point of the domain.
This claim is needed to prove Montel's Theorem. In Complex Analysis by Gamelin it is proved as follows:
If $z_0 \in D$, there exists a positive $r$ such that the closed disk {$|z-z_0 |\leq r$} is contained in D. The family is uniformly bounded on the  disk. By Cauchy's estimates, the derivatives of the functions in F are uniformly bounded on the smaller disk {$|z-z_0 |\leq r-\epsilon$}. Hence F is equicontinuous on each $z_0 \in D$.
Could someone explain how the statement in bold can be proved? All I am getting out of Cauchy's estimates is that assuming F uniformly bounded by M, for every $z_0 \in D$ there exists some postive r such that $|f'(z_0)|<\frac{M}{r}$ for all f in F. But this r is not necessarily the same for each $z_0$.

Note that if $f$ is holomorphic and $f'$ is bounded by $K$ in some closed ball $\overline{B_{r_{z_0}}(z_0)}$, then $f$ is Lipschitz in this closed ball. Indeed, let $z,w\in\overline{B_{r_{z_0}}(z_0)}$ and consider the path (inside the closed ball): $\gamma(t)=(1-t)z+tw,\,t\in [0,1]$.
Then:
$$|f(z)-f(w)|=\left |\int_{\gamma}f'(z)dz\right |\leq \int_0^1 \left |f'(\gamma(t))\right|\cdot |z-w|dt\leq K|z-w|$$
Now, what they proved is that for every $z_0\in D$, the family $F$ has a neighborhood in which they are all Lipschitz with constant $K_{z_0}$ (as you said, dependent on $z_0$), but they all share the same Lipschitz constant in the neighborhood that corresponds to $z_0$.
Now let's show that this implies equicontinuity at each $z_0$ - indeed fix $z_0\in D$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta=\frac{\min\{\frac{r_{z_0}}{\varepsilon}\}}{K_{z_0}}$. Then if $|z-z_0|<\delta$:
$$|f(z)-f(z_0)|\leq K_{z_0}|z-z_0|<K_{z_0}\delta\leq\varepsilon$$
as wanted.
